# catastrophic backstring in regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am using below regular expression

```
[^\/]*([A-Za-z]+_([A-Za-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(\.[A_Z0-9]+)?|(?:_|:|:-|-[a-zA-Z]+|\.[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+|=|\s|\?|\%|\.|!|#|\*)?)+(?=(,|\/)))+|,[^\/]*
```

and it showing me catastrophic backstring  when i am trying to match with input string.

```
/w_100/h_500/e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue/c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc/1488800313_DSC_0334__3_.JPG_mweubp.jpg
```

The expected output array of the matching regex will be like

```
[ 'w_100',
  'h_500',
  'e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue',
  'c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum.',
  'l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc' ]
```

don't want to consider image name 1488800313_DSC_0334__3_.JPG_mweubp.jpg in match. the following

is there any method to solve this backstrack in regular expression or suggest me good regex for my input string.

Comment: could you show us pls input, and expected output?

Comment: input:  /w_100/h_500/e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue/c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc/1488800313_DSC_0334__3_.JPG_mweubp.jpg  and                                                                                                                              
expected output :  [w_100,h_500,e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue,c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc]

Comment: Youd should not use such a complex RegEx. It is hard to read, mantain and expensive to the CPU. Try to parse / split the string in chuncks before applying a RegEx.

Comment: @Azevedo or parse/split the string in chunks *instead* of using a regex.

Comment: @Azevedo I know regular expression is like hell hard to understand but  in my case have to share full regex.

Comment: I don't really have time to find a regex solution, but I can tell why it is failing: it's because of the `_`'s in the file name. Because you are using generic patterns with letters and `_` to detect the key words such as `w_100`. The regex tries for each quantifier to get the maximum matching elements, and if the end of string is reached and there are still patterns to match, it starts to backtrack, but there are too many combinations. Getting rid of the filename, or to forbid `_` in the file names would solve this..

Answer (score 5):

### The problem

You use a lot of alternations when a character class would be more effective. Also, you're getting the catastrophic backtracking due to the following quantifier:

```
[^\/]*([A-Za-z]+_([A-Za-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(\.[A_Z0-9]+)?|(?:_|:|:-|-[a-zA-Z]+|\.[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+|=|\s|\?|\%|\.|!|#|\*)?)+(?=(,|\/)))+|,[^\/]*
                                                                                                                           ^
```

It's trying to match any of the alternations you have, but keeps backtracking and never makes it past all your alternations (it's sometimes comparable to an infinite loop). In your case, your regex is so ineffective that it times out. I removed half your pattern and it takes a half second to complete with almost 200K steps (and that's only half your pattern).

---

## Original Answer

### How can it be fixed?

First step is to fix the quantifier and prevent it from continuously backtracking. This is actually quite easy, just make it *possessive*: `+` becomes `++`. Changing the quantifier to possessive yields a pattern that takes about 56ms to complete and approx 9K steps (on my computer)

Second step is to improve the efficiency of the pattern. Change your alternations to character classes where possible.

```
(?:_|:|:-|-[a-zA-Z]+|\.[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+|=|\s|\?|\%|\.|!|#|\*)?
# should instead be
(?::-|[_:-=\s?%.!#*]|[-.][a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+)?
```

It's much shorter, much more concise and less prone to errors.

### The new pattern

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/1)

This pattern only takes 271 steps and less than one millisecond to complete (yes, using PCRE engine, works in Java too)

```
(?<=[,\/])[A-Za-z]+_(?:[A-Z0-9a-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)?|:-|[_:-=\s?%.!#*]|[-.][a-zA-Z]+)++
```

I also changed your positive lookahead to a positive lookbehind `(?<=[,\/])` to improve performance.

---

Additionally, if you don't need all the specific logic, you can quite simply use the following regex (just under half as many steps as my regex above):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/2)

```
(?<=[,\/])[A-Za-z]+_[^,\/]+
```

#### Results

This results in the following array:

<sub>P.S. I'm assuming there'a a typo in your expected output and that the `/` between `l_text` and `l_fetch` should also be split on; needs clarification.</sub>

```
w_100
h_500
e_saturation:50
e_tint:red:blue
c_crop
a_100
l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum.
l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc
```

---

## Edit #1

The OP clarified the expected results. I added `,` to the character class in the fourth option of the non-capture group:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/4)

```
(?<=[,\/])[A-Za-z]+_(?:[A-Z0-9a-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Z0-9]+)?|:-|[_:-=\s?%.!#*,]|[-.][a-zA-Z]+)++
```

And in its shortened form:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/5)

```
(?<=\/)[A-Za-z]+_[^\/]+
```

#### Results

This results in the following array:

```
w_100
h_500
e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue
c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum.
l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc
```

---

## Edit #2

The OP presented another input and identified issues with Edit #1 related to that input. I added logic to force a fail on the last item in a string.

New test string:

```
/w_100/h_500/e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue/c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc/sample_url_image.jpg
```

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/8)

```
(?<=\/)(?![A-Za-z]+_[^\/]+$)[A-Za-z]+_[^\/]+
```

Same results as in Edit #1.

---

PCRE version (if anyone is looking for it) - more efficient than the method above:

See regex in use here[enter link description here](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Uj8p/7)

```
(?<=\/)[A-Za-z]+_[^\/]+(?:$(*SKIP)(*FAIL))?
```

Comment: hey thank you for your great efforts. it works fine now. Sorry there is typo in my last o/p. I can not use your RESULTS section regex: (?<=[,\/])[A-Za-z]+_[^,\/]+ because what i need is match array of between / to / e.g. [ 'e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue' ] in my input string. and there's thousand of different pattern input string.

Comment: @Keval can you update your results section to clearly display each result item? I can change the regex, but want to ensure I provide you with the results you’re expecting

Comment: ye sure.. I edited expected output in main question.

Comment: I just did replace + to ++ and  (?:_|:|:-|-[a-zA-Z]+|\.[a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+|=|\s|\?|\%|\.|!|#|\*)? to  (?::-|[_:-=\s?%.!#*]|[-.][a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+)?.  and it is working well and regex is working fine and i am also getting what i want. but if you think still there's modification required then please. I am fine with all.

Comment: @Keval great thank you! I’ll be back in a few hours and add to my original answer to provide you with more accurate results based on your updated output. You could just drop the `,` from the regex `(?<=\/)[A-Za-z]+_[^\/]+`

Comment: Hey this regex which is working fine in PCRE (PHP) but didn't work in javascript. The regex i using is -  /[^\/]*([A-Za-z]+_([A-Za-z]+|-?[A-Z0-9]+(\.[A_Z0-9]+)?|(?::-|[_:-=\s?%.!#*]|[-.][a-zA-Z]+|[A-Z0-9a-z]+)?)+(?=(,|\/)))+|,[^\/]*/g   It gives me pattern error. could you please check.

Comment: Hey , this regex not generate true output every case.  Can you please check one more time. don't consider the  image name just ignore it. but for this type of input string /w_100/h_500/e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue/c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc/sample_url_image.jpg it's also consider ['sample_url_image.jpg'] in match array. do you know how to solve for this type of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example has a typo, e.g. the last `/` would be split too:

You can simply split on `/`, then filter out the `.jpg` items:

```
function splitWithFilter(line, filter) {
    var filterRe = filter ? new RegExp(filter, 'i') : null;
    return line
    .replace(/^\//, '') // remove leading /
    .split(/\//)
    //.filter(Boolean)    // filter out empty items (alternative to above replace())
    .filter(function(item) {
        return !filterRe || !item.match(filterRe);
    });
}

var str = "/w_100/h_500/e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue/c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum./l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc/1488800313_DSC_0334__3_.JPG_mweubp.jpg";
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitWithFilter(str, '\\.jpg$'), null, ' '));
```

Expected output:

```
[
 "w_100",
 "h_500",
 "e_saturation:50,e_tint:red:blue",
 "c_crop,a_100,l_text:Neucha_26_bold:Loremipsum.",
 "l_fetch:aHR0cDovL2Nsb3VkaW5hcnkuY29tL2ltYWdlcy9vbGRfbG9nby5wbmc"
]
```